# Overflow in footer

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, footer

I have a footer with the follow code:

```
<div class="footer" style="width: 100%;"><h5>
 <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%; background: #030534; color: white;" href="descontos.html">Vantagens</a> 
 <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%;" href="descubra.html">Novidades</a>
 <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%;" href="divulgue.html">Divulgue</a>
 </h5></div>
```

The css code are:

```
.footer {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.footer a {
  display: block;
  color: #030534;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change background on mouse-over */
.footer a:hover {
  background: #030534;
  color: white;
}
```

[And the result is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIPK2.png)

However, I want add more fields in this footer and want that works sliding. I cant do this. When I add another field, with this code:

```
<div class="footer" style="width: 100%;"><h5>
  <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%; background: #030534; color: white;" href="descontos.html">Vantagens</a> 
  <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%;" href="descubra.html">Novidades</a>
  <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%;" href="divulgue.html">Divulgue</a>
  <a style="width: 30%; float: left; margin-left: 2.5%;" href="descubra.html">TEST</a>
  </h5></div>
```

[And the result are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Iq5.png)

How to I add a overflow footer?

Thanks for all!

Comment: I highly recommend you to not mix up inline-style which has the highest specificity weight with actual css (lowest specificity weight). Also dont use `float` to align items next to eachother. use flexbox instead! Your overflow is caused because `4 x 30% = 120%` which is wider then the parent. You have to adjust the width to fit.

Comment: Hi, but I wanna cause a overflow. This idea is insert about 10 fields and have  scroll on the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help you, see snippet

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.footer a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #030534;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change background on mouse-over */

.footer a:hover {
  background: #030534;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer" style="width: 100%;">
  <a style="margin-left: 2.5%; background: #030534; color: white;" href="descontos.html">Vantagens</a>
  <a style="margin-left: 2.5%;" href="descubra.html">Novidades</a>
  <a style="margin-left: 2.5%;" href="divulgue.html">Divulgue</a>
  <a style="margin-left: 2.5%;" href="descubra.html">TEST</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `inline-flex` instead of `flex;` + `nowrap`

Comment: @tacoshy I did not know about inlin-flex and I did not use it much and it works in a shorter way